# Client cannot authenticate via: [TOKEN, KERBEROS] when running hive query from Spark on a remote cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

We have a setup where we have 2 clusters, production cluster A and development cluster B. In cluster B Hive tables are created pointing to HDFS in cluster A (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_data-access/content/querying-remote-clusters.html). We can successfully query tables in cluster B and data is returned as expected (records stored in cluster A), then we have some PySpark code that queries the tables using:

```
sqlContext.sql("query tables in B that point to HDFS in A")
```

That code works fine in interactive PySpark sessions, but when running as a batch job we get:

```
org.apach.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via: [TOKEN,KERBEROS]
```

Given it works in interactive mode it seems to me some type of configuration or permission(or maybe Kerberos) could fix it, but some members in support team believe it's a limitation from Spark that cannot be fixed, how can we make this 2 cluster with 1 dev cluster pointing to HDFS in another production cluster work with batch spark code?

Comment: are you using spark submit command to execute spark ??

Comment: It's a custom wrapper on top of spark-submit, but yes, in the end it goes through spark-submit.

Comment: I think your clusters are kerberos enabled, are you passing keytab files to spark-submit ?

Comment: Yes, they are kerberos enabled, and not sure abut the passing of the keytab, i'm end user and i use the custom wrapper so i just provide the script and command line parameters to it, i'll try to get input from support/admin teams.

Comment: Mostly we are passing these two configs with spark-submit ```--conf spark.yarn.keytab=/path/to/<service_account>.keytab``` & 
```--conf spark.yarn.principal=principal@REALM.COM ```

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was to add the following config:

```
.config("spark.yarn.access.namenodes", "hdfs://cluster_A")
```